# Android launching default activity to dashboard or different activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Am developing an app which am using a dashboard. I want the dashboard to be the default activity. If user opens the app for the first time or has logged out, i want to redirect him to login/sign up page as the first page. If user has already signed in i want to direct him to dashboard as the default page. how can i accomplice this. Is there a good tutorial on this, i will appreciate most. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
class AuthenticatedActivity extends Activity{
  onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    if(!isAuthenticated()){
      Intent showAuthActivityIntent = new Intent();
      startActivityForResult(showAuthActivity);
      finish();
      return;
    }
  }
}

class AnyActivity extends AuthenticatedActivity{
  onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    if(isFinishing())
      return;
  }
}
```

And have your dashboard as the launcher Activity.

Modify the `isAuthenticated()` block to make it suitable to your use-case.

You might also want to make your SignupActivity a singleton Activity.

Comment: Thanks, could you direct a sample example which i can look at?

Answer (score 0):

Your login screen activity will be your main activity. here in this activity you can check by setting some flag whether the login details exists if exists you can redirect to the dashboard activity, in manifest you have to set the login as your default main activity.